# How to debug a Magento 2 project on Visual Studio or PhpStorm in Windows 10 with WSL2 Environment using Nginx and PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, windows, debugging, wsl-2

I'm currently working on a Magento 2 project and need guidance on debugging it effectively within a Windows 10 environment utilizing WSL2, Nginx, and PHP 8.1. My primary development tools are Visual Studio and PhpStorm, and I want to ensure seamless debugging capabilities while working on this project.

I Was tried some google solution but no luck. can please give any idea. how to fix ?